# Can I display a pandas data frame over a range of index values (multiple rows)?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

A way to display a table including the first row of a data frame (index = 0) and all columns is the following:

```
    some_variable = df.loc[0, :]
```

Is there a way to so this same thing over multiple index values (displaying a range of rows)?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you want to print some top rows.

1. If you want top n rows

```
    print(df.head(n))
```

2. If you want to print a set of rows.

```
    print(df.loc[[id1,id2,id3],:])
```

Comment: 2nd was what I was looking for, thank you. I'm just looking now for a way to remove the displayed indices for each row